# Firebase with IntelXDK (Cordova) does not fire update events

Tags: firebase, intel-xdk

I have a HTML5 app within an Intel-XDK project and I'm writing to Firebase. When I test the app from a desktop browser, everything works fine. When however I run the app on my Android device (built by Intel-XDK build process), Firebase `update` events do not fire. To get the events to fire, I need to send the app to the background, then activate it again - only then do I see the updates coming through to the Firebase Console.

Android version 5.1.1, Tab A

My **update** code:

```
var updates = {};
updates['users/' + user.uid + '/devices/' + uuid] = "some data";        
updates['devices/' + uuid + '/user'] = "some data";
updates['devices/' + uuid + '/last'] = "some data";

firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Is it a browser issue perhaps?

Comment: I've found `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner` to be a problem too. Once the scanner returns from a scan, I loose connectivity to Firebase.

Comment: Calling `navigator.notification.confirm(...)` when the scanner returns causes the Firebase connection to be restored.